# How I do select those entries in SQL which are greater than a certain time using datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a MySQL database, with the first column for index (auto incrementing), and the 2nd column as datetime. I want to select all entries greater than a certain date and time and display them.

To see date and time greater than a select value, this works-

```
SELECT * FROM FULL_WATSON_V2 WHERE (datetime > '2014-06-25 17:22:00');
```

But the user will just input how much earlier from now does it want data, and using this form is cumbersome. For example, the user will specify that it wants data starting from 2 hours and 40 minutes ago.

What's the best way to write an SQL query for this?

PS - I believe datepart() can be used in some way, but I was unable to get it to work.

Comment: WHERE datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 40 MINUTES ?

Comment: Decide what the user input should look like.  Then delete this question and ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you stick with the query as you have, as that is the context agnostic version of finding records. The fact that UI specifies the time as an offset from the current time is a business logic decision and should not filter down to your SQL.

I.e. the UI that captures the offset should determine the smaller than date from the current time and use it as the input for your query, rather than having an SQL query that relies on calculating that offset.